# What is peer in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I thought peer in hyper ledger fabric is the only endorser.

However, According to the doc, Endorsement policy can specify 'Org.member'.

If member can endorse transaction, what is peer.
What does endorsement policy define? Can member endorse? What is peer role? Peer role differs from peer?

Document(https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/endorsement-policies.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/peers/peers.html.

In general, I prefer to specify `Org.peer` in my endorsement policies, as it is more restrictive than `Org.member`.

Comment: Peer role is just a name of role? My understanding is that,  Peer role has just a semantic meaning, and expected to be endorsement peer, but has no techniccal meaning.  Other roles also can be endorsement peer. Right ?

Comment: About the syntax: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/endorsement-policies.html#endorsement-policy-syntax. It's all about the roles that are allowed/required in the endorsement signatures. Said that, I always use `Org.peer`. The role is read from the X.509 certificate corresponding to the signature (not sure if from the `OU`or from the `hf.Type` attribute).